Finding BLE Services
I'm trying to connect a smartphone running Android 13 to a server using BLE. Android 11 connects and finds services, but Android 13 can't find them. I have tried everything with permissions
I'd like to find a recommendation for searching services from Android 13

Welcome to Stack Overflow. IIt is important to read the necessary documentation. I think you may have missed the part about runtime permissions.

Can you please post your code/pseudo-code and the permissions that you have enabled?

Android 12 introduces new permission requirements. Please read the doc for details

Does this answer your question? Android 12 New Bluetooth Permissions

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Before Android 12 (API level 31), Bluetooth permissions were bundled with location permissions.  Starting with Android 12, Google separated Bluetooth permissions into two distinct permissions: BLUETOOTH_SCAN for scanning nearby Bluetooth devices, and BLUETOOTH_CONNECT for establishing connections to Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices.
If your app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or lower, you need to declare the following permissions in your app's manifest file, and the location must be turned ON for scanning.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


BLUETOOTH permission to make connection to Bluetooth device.
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to scan for Bluetooth devices.

If your app targets Android 12 (API level 31) or higher alone, declare the following permissions in your app's manifest file:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />


BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission to make connection to Bluetooth device.
BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission to scan for Bluetooth devices.

neverForLocation flag is necessary or else scan will not work properly.
If your app targets Android 12 (API level 31) or higher and below Android 11, declare the following permissions in your app's manifest file:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />

NB: If your app targets Android 12 (API level 31) or higher and you are scanning for a BLE beacon device,
don't add flag neverForLocation and the location must be turned ON for scanning.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

I suspect the BLE device you are trying to connect is a BLE beacon (or something with a location service), since you are granting location permission in Android 11 it will work properly. But it may not work properly in Android 12+ try removing
android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
android:maxSdkVersion="30"

and use the below permission in the manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

and turn ON Location also.
